# Login via ssh to last used folder

Tags: ssh, login, directory

I have simple question. Is there any chance to configure ssh in that way, when I login to my server via ssh I want be in last used directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you are using bash as shell.

edit .bash_logout in you home dir, add a line like

```
pwd > $HOME/.last-pwp
```

edit .bash_profile, add a line like

```
cd $(< $HOME/.last-pwp )
```

note that if you run many session in parallel, only one directory will be remembered.

Comment: I think you meant `.last-pwd` but the point is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One great tool to do this is [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) it is a powerful replacement to the old [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Tmux allows you to create sessions and detach/attach from/to these sessions: then you can disconnect from your server and find your directory when you log back but you can also start a program, disconnect while it is running and reconnect after its execution.

Once you've installed tmux on your server you can use the following command to connect to your server and attach the last tmux session (of course you can easily alias it):

```
ssh user@server -t tmux a
```

Once you're done on your server you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to detach the session and disconnect. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> is tmux leader and can be configured in a `~/.tmux.conf` file)

Answer (score 0):

this command added to `.bashrc`

```
last_command () { pwd > $HOME/.last-pwp; }
trap last_command EXIT
cd $(< $HOME/.last-pwp)
```

works even when exiting the console by closing the window instead of `exit` or `logout`, at least in Fedora