# Preserve OLDPWD after logging out

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I often need to go to the directory I was when I logged out of a server. I habitually use `cd -` for this purpose. However, after logging out and logging back in this does not work because apparently `OLDPWD` gets reset:

```
$ cd -
-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set
```

Is there a way to preserve the value of `OLDPWD` beyond a login session in bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login via ssh to last used folder](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228762/login-via-ssh-to-last-used-folder)

Comment: When you have favorite directories you want to visit often, you can add an alias for each dir in your `.bashrc`:
alias cdx='cd $HOME/a/very/deep/dir/xantippe'
alias cdlog='cd /var/mytool/log'
alias cdtest='cd $HOME/test'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for me, it seems like the easiest approach would be the creation of a .oldpwd file that stores the last pwd location between sessions.

For this you can use the ~/.bash_logout (if using BASH) or ~/.logout (if using tcsh/csh).

Just put some lines like this in the ~/.logout (or ~/.bash_logout)

```
echo $(pwd) > ~/.oldpwd
```

and something like this in the ~/.profile (or ~./bash_profile)

```
export OLDPWD=$(cat ~/.oldpwd)
```

Comment: great idea; more simply, have .bash_logout do `env | grep OLDPWD > ~/.oldpwd`, and have .bash_profile do `. ~/.oldpwd`

Comment: There you , I'm glad the idea helped you!

Comment: Setting PWD or OLDPWD  triggers unspecified behavior.  A shell could emit pink smoke instead of what you indent.